# Rollback rake db:seed if exception is raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My seeds file runs through quite a few csv files, does a few checks and creates various ActiveRecord records accordingly.  While testing all these files, I finally think I have it and run `rake db:seed` but if something fails, I want what has been created so far to rollback.

Scenario that has already happened:

1. Seeds file requires 4 different CSV's
2. Only 3 of the 4 CSV's were uploaded to staging server
3. `rake db:seed` was run and the seeds file blew up half way through because it couldn't find a file, but over 1000 AR objects were created prior to that.

Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
begin
  CSV.readlines(file1)
  CSV.readlines(file2)
  CSV.readlines(file3)
  CSV.readlines(file4)
rescue
  # raise an error
  # rollback all objects created prior to error
end
```

I suppose I could implement something custom but I can't find anything on the rails guides regarding this.

Comment: This is initial data?  Could you destroy_all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of [Active Record Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

> Transactions are protective blocks where SQL statements are only
>   permanent if they can all succeed as one atomic action. The classic
>   example is a transfer between two accounts where you can only have a
>   deposit if the withdrawal succeeded and vice versa. Transactions
>   enforce the integrity of the database and guard the data against
>   program errors or database break-downs. So basically you should use
>   transaction blocks whenever you have a number of statements that must
>   be executed together or not at all.

Try this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ...
end
```

Comment: After reading [about Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) this looks perfect.